# Remove whitespace after css translate animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I want to animate a a collection of divs on a page (`#sections`) in such a way that a the first div (`#splash`) acts a splash page to greet the user and then can never be scrolled to again/removed. I have done this using css transforms but whitespace is revealed where `#sections` previously occupied. How can I achieve this functionality whilst not revealing whitespace?

```js
const sections = document.querySelector('#sections');
const body = document.body;

function intro() {
    body.classList = 'hide-splash'
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        intro()
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#splash,
#main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
#sections {
  transform: translateY(0vh);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
.hide-splash #sections {
  transform: translateY(-100vh);
}





#splash {
  background-color: #ffa500;
}
#main {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}
#secondary {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
footer {
  background-color: Aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sections">
            <div id="splash">SPLASH</div>
            <div id="main">MAIN</div>
            <div id="secondary">
                <ul>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <ul>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                </ul>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thought about using a CSS reset? https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Do you mean whitespace between splash, main and other divs?

Answer (score 0):

There is many options:

```js
const sections = document.querySelector('#sections');
const body = document.body;

function intro() {
    body.classList = 'hide-splash'
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        intro()
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#splash,
#main {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
#splash {
  transition: transform 1s, height 1s;
}
.hide-splash #splash {
  transform: translateY(-100vh);
  height: 0;
}


#splash {
  background-color: #ffa500;
}
#main {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}
#secondary {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
footer {
  background-color: Aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sections">
            <div id="splash">SPLASH</div>
            <div id="main">MAIN</div>
            <div id="secondary">
                <ul>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                    <li>SECONDARY</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <ul>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                    <li>FOOTER</li>
                </ul>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```